# How to check whether ifstream is end of file in C++

Tags: c++, ifstream, file-handling, line-endings, seekg

I need to read all blocks of one large file(about 10GB) sequentially, the file contains many floats with a few strings, like this(each item splited by '\n'):

`6.292611
-1.078219E-266
-2.305673E+065
sod;eiwo
4.899747e-237
1.673940e+089
-4.515213`

I read `MAX_NUM_PER_FILE` items each time and process them and write to another file, but i don't know when the `ifstream` is ended.
Here is my code:

```
ifstream file_input(path_input);  //my file is a text file, but i tried  both text and binary mode, both failed.
if(file_input)
{
    file_input.seekg(0,file_input.end);
    unsigned long long length = file_input.tellg();    //get file size
    file_input.seekg(0,file_input.beg);

    char * buffer = new char [MAX_NUM_PER_FILE+MAX_NUM_PER_LINE];
    int i=1,j;
    char c,tmp[3];
    while(file_input.tellg()<length)
    {
        file_input.read(buffer,MAX_NUM_PER_FILE);
        j=MAX_NUM_PER_FILE;
        while(file_input.get(c)&&c!='\n')
            buffer[j++]=c;   //get a complete item

        //process with buffer...

        itoa(i++,tmp,10);    //int2char
        string out_name="out"+string(tmp)+".txt";
        ofstream file_output(out_name);
        file_output.write(buffer,j);
        file_output.close();
    }

    file_input.close();
    delete[] buffer;
}
```

My code goes wrong, `length` is bigger than real file size. I have tried `file_input.good()` or `!file_input.eof()`, they didn't work, `getline(file_input,s)` is good, but it is much slower than `read`, i want `read`, but i don't know how to check whether `ifstream` is end-of-file.

I do my work in WINDOWS 7 with VS2010.

I have searched, but there are not any answer about it, [How to open a file using ifstream and keep reading it until the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804043/how-to-open-a-file-using-ifstream-and-keep-reading-it-until-the-end) this link can't answer my question.

---

**Update, Problem solved**

Hi everyone, I have figured it out that it's my fault. Both `while(file_input.tellg()<length)` and `while(file_input.peek()!=EOF)` work fine! `while(file_input.peek()!=EOF)` is recommended.

**The extra items written after the end-of-file is the left items in `buffer` written in the last time.**

Here is the correct code:

```
ifstream file_input(path_input);
if(file_input)
{
    //file_input.seekg(0,file_input.end);
    //unsigned long long length = file_input.tellg();   //get file size
    //file_input.seekg(0,file_input.beg);

    char * buffer = new char [MAX_NUM_PER_FILE+MAX_NUM_PER_LINE];
    int i=1,j;
    char c,tmp[3];
    while(file_input.peek()!=EOF)
    {
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(char)*(MAX_NUM_PER_FILE+MAX_NUM_PER_LINE));  //clear first!
        file_input.read(buffer,MAX_NUM_PER_FILE);
        j=MAX_NUM_PER_FILE;
        while(file_input.get(c)&&c!='\n')
            buffer[j++]=c;

        itoa(i++,tmp,10);//int2char
        string out_name="out"+string(tmp)+".txt";
        ofstream file_output(out_name);
        file_output.write(buffer,strlen(buffer));   //use the correct buffer size instead of j
        file_output.close();
    }

    file_input.close();
    delete[] buffer;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be checking EOF *before* reading. Attempt to read, and check if it succeeded.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant You mean `while(file_input.read(buffer,MAX_NUM_PER_FILE))` ?  I tried this, but it can read all the file, a few items aren't be readed.

Comment: @MSalters I don't think the linked question actually answers this one.

Comment: Seems I picked the wrong Q from the list of possible duplicates, which TBH is a rather big list. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong?lq=1 (highest voted Q&A on `.eof()`)

Comment: Another indicator of a failed STL design, as if asking for size or end of stream was too extraordinary.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
while( file_input.peek() != EOF )
{
    // code
}
```

Basically `peek()` will read the next `char` without extracting it.

So you can simply compare it to `EOF`.

Comment: It still get more wrong `char` after end-of-file just like `while(file_input.tellg()<length)`.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. Your solution works, see my update. Thank you.

Comment: Does this also work for a binary file opened in `read | write` mode? Does it work for binary streams at all?